# Trigger with a function Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I need to make a trigger to insert 'A' in case of a approved student and 'R' for a not approved student. I need to use a function that returns 'A' or 'R'. Here is my function:

```
create or replace function check_grade
(grade in number, frequency in number) return varchar2
as 
result varchar2(1) default '';
begin
if(grade>=6) and (frequency>=0.75)then
result := 'A';
else
result := 'R';
end if;
return result;
end;
```

And here is my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger situation
before 
insert on student
for each row
begin
select check_grade(grade, frequency)
into : new.situation
from dual;
end;
```

When I try to execute I always get an error. I don't have idea in what i can do!

Comment: Please post the ddl of the table/tables in use

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message you're seeing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined functions are allowed in triggers, and your function looks OK.

One definite problem with your trigger is that it mentions `grade` and `frequency`, which are variable names, and they haven't been declared. I'll assume you probably meant to use the inserted column values instead: `:new.grade` and `:new.frequency`.

Also, I've always set "new" values using simple variable assignment (`:new.value := blah` instead of `select blah into :new.value from dual`). Your way may work (or may not - I don't know), but the simple variable assignment syntax is a lot shorter and it's easy enough to read.

So try replacing these three lines:

```
select check_grade(grade, frequency)
into : new.situation
from dual;
```

... with this one line:

```
:new.situation := check_grade(:new.grade, :new.frequency);
```

If this doesn't work then please update the question and replace *"I always get an error"* with *I get error ORA-<actual-error-number>*. Include the stack trace, which will show if the function or the trigger is throwing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but do i need to input this in the "into" line?

Answer (score 0):

The function isn't needed here; it can be replaced by a CASE expression:

```
create or replace trigger situation
  before insert on student
  for each row
begin
  :new.situation := CASE
                      WHEN grade >= 6 and frequency >= 0.75 THEN 'A'
                      ELSE 'R';
                    END;
end situation;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's an exercise, I need to use the function.